# What is the equivelent of HttpChannel.getCurrentHttpChannel().getHttpConfiguration(); in Jetty 9.3

Tags: jetty

In [jetty 9.2](http://javadox.com/org.eclipse.jetty/jetty-server/9.2.0.RC0/org/eclipse/jetty/server/HttpChannel.html#getCurrentHttpChannel()) there was a `getCurrentHttpChannel` method on `HttpChannel` and we use this like `HttpChannel.getCurrentHttpChannel().getHttpConfiguration();`

I would now like to convert to [Jetty 9.3](http://download.eclipse.org/jetty/9.3.9.v20160517/apidocs/org/eclipse/jetty/server/HttpChannel.html) but that method is missing and I cannot find any references, in docs etc, to what has changed. Is there an equivalent in 9.3?

Comment: First, why do you need access to the HttpChannel and/or the HttpConfiguration during runtime?

Comment: @JoakimErdfelt This is code I inherited not wrote but it has to do with manually configuring the jetty instance on the startup of the executable JAR

Comment: You cannot configure the `HttpConfiguration` successfully (or reliably) after the server has been started.  The `HttpConfiguration` should only be configured once, before you add any `Connector` that uses it, and before you call `Server.start()`.

Answer (score 3):

In Jetty 9.3 the following is available to do this:

```
HttpConnection.getCurrentConnection().getHttpChannel().getHttpConfiguration();
```

Answer (score 1):

Nearly all of the Thread Local access methods to the internals of Jetty have been removed, as they are invalid when used within HTTP/2, WebSocket, and various other client contexts.

If you have a need to access the internals of Jetty, you have to do that outside of ServletContext.

Eg: [SecuredRedirectHandler](https://github.com/eclipse/jetty.project/blob/jetty-9.3.11.v20160721/jetty-server/src/main/java/org/eclipse/jetty/server/handler/SecuredRedirectHandler.java)

```java
/* License: Eclipse Public License 1.0 and Apache License 2.0
 * See linked source file above for details.
 */
package org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler;

import java.io.IOException;

import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

import org.eclipse.jetty.http.HttpStatus;
import org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel;
import org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConfiguration;
import org.eclipse.jetty.server.Request;
import org.eclipse.jetty.util.URIUtil;

/**
 * Secured Redirect Handler
 * <p>
 * Using information present in the {@link HttpConfiguration}, will attempt to redirect to the {@link HttpConfiguration#getSecureScheme()} and
 * {@link HttpConfiguration#getSecurePort()} for any request that {@link HttpServletRequest#isSecure()} == false.
 */
public class SecuredRedirectHandler extends AbstractHandler
{
    @Override
    public void handle(String target, Request baseRequest, HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException, ServletException
    {
        HttpChannel channel = baseRequest.getHttpChannel();
        if (baseRequest.isSecure() || (channel == null))
        {
            // nothing to do
            return;
        }

        HttpConfiguration httpConfig = channel.getHttpConfiguration();
        if (httpConfig == null)
        {
            // no config, show error
            response.sendError(HttpStatus.FORBIDDEN_403,"No http configuration available");
            return;
        }

        if (httpConfig.getSecurePort() > 0)
        {
            String scheme = httpConfig.getSecureScheme();
            int port = httpConfig.getSecurePort();

            String url = URIUtil.newURI(scheme,baseRequest.getServerName(),port,baseRequest.getRequestURI(),baseRequest.getQueryString());
            response.setContentLength(0);
            response.sendRedirect(url);
        }
        else
        {
            response.sendError(HttpStatus.FORBIDDEN_403,"Not Secure");
        }

        baseRequest.setHandled(true);
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you add a little bit about how to register these handlers once created?

Comment: NM this looks like a good explanation... https://www.eclipse.org/jetty/documentation/9.3.x/embedding-jetty.html